# How could a 'byte string' input argument be passed to a python function called from MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to call a Python function from MATLAB. In this Python function, an input argument is of type 'byte string'. I was not able to pass 'byte string' arguments to Python

I am trying to create a server-client application using ipc, where server is a pure Python application and client is a MATLAB application which calls python functions. I have Anaconda installed with Python 3.7 environment.

Python Server code :

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener

address = ('localhost', 6000)     # family is deduced to be 'AF_INET'
listener = Listener(address, authkey=b'secret password')
conn = listener.accept()
print('connection accepted from', listener.last_accepted)
while True:
    msg = conn.recv()
    print(msg)
    if msg == 'close':
        conn.close()
        break
listener.close()
```

Python client code (for testing purpose):

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Client

address = ('localhost', 6000)
conn = Client(address, authkey=b'secret password')
conn.send('close')
can also send arbitrary objects:
conn.send(['a', 2.5, None, int, sum])
conn.close()
```

When executed in Python, the above server-client pair is working fine.

Now trying MATLAB equivalent of above Python client code in command line :

```
>> mp_pyModule = py.importlib.import_module('multiprocessing.connection');
>> client_fn = mp_pyModule.Client;
>> address = py.tuple({'localhost',int16(6000)});
>> conn = client_fn(address,pyargs('authkey','secret password'));
Error using connection>Client (line 495)
Python Error: TypeError: authkey should be a byte string
```

I know I have passed a normal string above and that is the reason for error. I require the above argument 'secret password' to be sent as a 'byte string'. How could it be done ?

Unsupported types to Python(https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/unsupported-matlab-types.html) does not mention anything about this. Is there any other limitation ? If I move to Python 2, this may work.

Comment: You could check out the [`c_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_byte) dtype, as the docs you linked seem to [support them](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-data-to-python.html)

Answer (score 0):

Solution found :
Use **py.bytes(uint8(string))**

eg:
`conn = client_fn(address,pyargs('authkey',py.bytes(uint8('secret password'))));`

credits - Walter Roberson@Mathworks